# VSO How to build a single solution in a Repository containing multiple

Tags: tfs, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are using **Visual Studio Team Services** as our source repository and for Build and Release.

**What I Want to do?**
We have a Repository that contains multiple directories in its root, each folder representing an ASP.NET Web Application. I want to use the Build feature to build a single solution in that repository.

**The Problem**
I can see the Build Agent downloading all source files for all folders/solutions in the Repository rather than just the solution I have selected.

Can someone provide the steps I need to take in order to only build one of the Solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using TFVC or Git?

Comment: TFVC - I have managed to figure this out myself.

Answer (score 0):

The source Directory wasn't mapped correctly, hence was downloading all sources from the Repository root. Set this correctly and all is working well, with the a slight amendment to the Drop directory